# performance between memory swapping and database

Tags: linux, ram, virtual-memory

I have an OpenCV program that will record many pictures in RAM in order to do some algorithm. So, the more ram I have, the more accuracy the algorithm will achieve.
Because of that, I decide to enable memory swapping or just write some of the pictures that exceed the maximum RAM size into database. The problem is which way is better.